# How to track down which process cause networkd to write a certain log line on Mac

Tags: networking, proxy, mac, console

When I open Console on my Mac, I see the following line written every 2 seconds:

```
1/6/16 3:26:55.808 PM networkd[206]: -[NETProxyLookup url] invalid URL scheme '19536'
```

It is written to system.log by networkd. It seems I have a proxy misconfigured somewhere (but I checked it's not the system-wide network preference). Is there a way to track down which process caused networkd to print this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is combination of 2 apps in your Mac (or at least mine).
First is Glimmerblocker, which throw out this error. The second one is LastPass which tries to open connection to localhost port 19536. ([reference](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=8176))